# Error installing JRuby with RVM on OS X 10.8

Tags: ruby, rvm, jruby

I'm running into an error when installing JRuby in RVM for OS X 10.8, terminal output is below when trying to install:

```
$ rvm install jruby --debug
jruby - install
jruby-1.7.0 - #downloading jruby-bin-1.7.0, this may take a while depending on your connection...
[2012-11-01 00:09:16] /usr/local/rvm/scripts/fetch http://jruby.org.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/1.7.0/jruby-bin-1.7.0.tar.gz
current path: /usr/local/rvm/src
command(2): /usr/local/rvm/scripts/fetch http://jruby.org.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/1.7.0/jruby-bin-1.7.0.tar.gz
jruby-1.7.0 - #extracting jruby-bin-1.7.0 to /usr/local/rvm/src/jruby-1.7.0
[2012-11-01 00:09:17] tar xzf /usr/local/rvm/archives/jruby-bin-1.7.0.tar.gz -C /usr/local/rvm/tmp/rvm_src_80980
current path: /usr/local/rvm/src
command(5): tar xzf /usr/local/rvm/archives/jruby-bin-1.7.0.tar.gz -C /usr/local/rvm/tmp/rvm_src_80980
jruby-1.7.0 - #extracted to /usr/local/rvm/src/jruby-1.7.0
jruby-1.7.0 - #nailgun
[2012-11-01 00:09:18] jruby_install_build_nailgun
jruby_install_build_nailgun () 
{ 
    typeset _result;
    set -x;
    chpwd_functions="" builtin cd "${rvm_src_path}/$rvm_ruby_string/tool/nailgun" && case "$rvm_ruby_version" in 
        1.2* | 1.3*)
            true
        ;;
        *)
            env "${rvm_configure_env[@]}" ./configure --prefix=$rvm_ruby_home
        ;;
    esac && make "${rvm_make_flags[@]}";
    _result=$?;
    set +x;
    return $_result
}
current path: /usr/local/rvm/src/jruby-1.7.0
command(1): jruby_install_build_nailgun
Error running 'jruby_install_build_nailgun', please read /usr/local/rvm/log/jruby-1.7.0/nailgun.log
```

The nailgun.log looks like this:

```
[2012-11-01 00:09:18] jruby_install_build_nailgun
jruby_install_build_nailgun () 
{ 
    typeset _result;
    set -x;
    chpwd_functions="" builtin cd "${rvm_src_path}/$rvm_ruby_string/tool/nailgun" && case "$rvm_ruby_version" in 
        1.2* | 1.3*)
            true
        ;;
        *)
            env "${rvm_configure_env[@]}" ./configure --prefix=$rvm_ruby_home
        ;;
    esac && make "${rvm_make_flags[@]}";
    _result=$?;
    set +x;
    return $_result
}
current path: /usr/local/rvm/src/jruby-1.7.0
command(1): jruby_install_build_nailgun
++ chpwd_functions=
++ builtin cd /usr/local/rvm/src/jruby-1.7.0/tool/nailgun
++ case "$rvm_ruby_version" in
++ env 'LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include' ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.0
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... 
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
++ _result=77
++ set +x
```

So it looks like there is a problem calling configure, config.log is below:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by ng configure 0.7.1, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.61.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.0

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = #####.local
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 12.2.0
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 12.2.0: Sat Aug 25 00:48:52 PDT 2012; root:xnu-2050.18.24~1/RELEASE_X86_64

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = Mach kernel version:
     Darwin Kernel Version 12.2.0: Sat Aug 25 00:48:52 PDT 2012; root:xnu-2050.18.24~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for up to 2 processors.
2 processors are physically available.
2 processors are logically available.
Processor type: i486 (Intel 80486)
Processors active: 0 1
Primary memory available: 8.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 146 tasks, 748 threads, 2 processors
Load average: 6.21, Mach factor: 0.29
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin
PATH: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin
PATH: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin
PATH: /usr/local/rvm/bin
PATH: /opt/local/bin
PATH: /opt/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /opt/sm/bin
PATH: /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin
PATH: /opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:1734: checking for gcc
configure:1750: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:1761: result: gcc
configure:1999: checking for C compiler version
configure:2006: gcc --version >&5
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:2009: $? = 0
configure:2016: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~67/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~67/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
configure:2019: $? = 0
configure:2026: gcc -V >&5
llvm-gcc-4.2: argument to `-V' is missing
configure:2029: $? = 1
configure:2052: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:2079: gcc   -L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include conftest.c  >&5
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include: No such file or directory
configure:2082: $? = 1
configure:2120: result: 
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "ng"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "ng"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.7.1"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "ng 0.7.1"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2127: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value='-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include'
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

CC='gcc'
CFLAGS=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
DEFS=''
ECHO_C='ECHO_N=''
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
GREP=''
LDFLAGS='-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include'
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME='ng'
PACKAGE_STRING='ng 0.7.1'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='ng'
PACKAGE_VERSION='0.7.1'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
SHELL='/bin/sh'
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build_alias=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host_alias=''
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.0'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

#define PACKAGE_NAME "ng"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "ng"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.7.1"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "ng 0.7.1"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""

configure: exit 77
```

Anyone have any idea what's going on? Tried for hours looking round different forums with no luck. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is not required to build nailgun in jruby 1.7.0, you can use rvm head where this step was already removed:

```
rvm get head
rvm reinstall jruby
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to install jruby with mac osx 10.8 without any problem.

```
$ rvm install jruby
jruby-1.7.0 - #downloading jruby-bin-1.7.0, this may take a while
depending on your connection... jruby-1.7.0 - #extracting
jruby-bin-1.7.0 to /Users/guy/.rvm/src/jruby-1.7.0 jruby-1.7.0 -
extracted to /Users/guy/.rvm/src/jruby-1.7.0 jruby-1.7.0 - #nailgun jruby-1.7.0 -    #installing to /Users/guy/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.0
jruby-1.7.0 - #importing default gemsets (/Users/guy/.rvm/gemsets/)
```

It seems that configure is failing, which might be that your gcc is outdated or for some reason not working properly.
Do you have Xcode installed and add the command line tools? This should fix your gcc problem.
If you don't want to get Xcode installed you can install gcc with homebrew or the likes.

Comment: I have XCode version 4.5.1 and the command line tools installed as well